# How can I Retrieve a UserRole with Valence query

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Is there some way that I can retrieve the `roleId` of the current user context regardless of that user's role permissions within the `LMS`?

For example, I would like to programatically determine if a user is a 'student', 'teacher', etc.  I know this can be done if the authenticated user has access to user roles but obviously a 'student' role would not possess such credentials.

Any insight into this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With many organizations the assigned role of a user's enrolment is considered sensitive information by the organization (for example, imagine the case where the organization wants to set up multiple roles for particular pay grades of instructors), and does not want the roles to be visible outside a small group of administrative users. Accordingly, there may not be a reliable way for a users to determine their *own* roleIds assigned to them within an organization unit (course, department, faculty, and so forth), let alone the roles assigned to other users.

Our typical recommendation is that client applications focus first on attempting actions that a user should be able to accomplish based on their access in the webUI: in some cases, this could involve a user characterizing their own general role in a context ("Are you a student in this course? An instructor? A Teaching Assistant?") or it could involve simply attempting actions and gracefully taking action based on results ("I'm sorry, you don't have permission to do/see that").

The various API calls that return an [`Enrollment.OrgUnitUser`](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#Enrollment.OrgUnitUser) structure will contain role information for enrollments; notably the [MyEnrollments](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-enrollments-myenrollments-) API call does not return such a structure (it's intention was to be a "safe" call that any user could make to fetch back the list of their own enrollments with potentially privileged information redacted).